# Getting HttpResponseNotFound in Django test get method

Tags: django, django-testing

I am building a test case for an endpoint. Visiting the endpoint in the local development using the browser works fine -- I get the expected response. However, during the test, I get an HttpResponseNotFound in which the endpoint is not found on the server.

```
#views.py
class ExampleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request):
        print('GOT HERE')
        qs = Example.objects.last()
        
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            if self.request.user.is_subscribed:
                message = {
                    'info': 'User can download template.',
                    'template': qs.file.url
                }
                return Response(message, status.HTTP_200_OK)

        message = {
            'info': 'User cannot download template.',
            'template': None
        }
        return Response(message, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

In my urls.py

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('request/download_template', ExampleView.as_view()),
]
```

My test build

```
class TestExample(APITestCase):
    fixtures = ['fixtures/initial', 'fixtures/auth', 'fixtures/example']

    def test_forecast_template_authenticated(self):
        response = self.client.get(
            '/request/download_template/')
        
        print('result', response)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The response

> <HttpResponseNotFound status_code=404, "text/html; charset=utf-8">

I am trying to debug but I do not even reach the print statement I have in my view. I have been figuring out where could be my mistake but its been hours. Why am I getting that response? Where could be my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your test you are using different url:

```
def test_forecast_template_authenticated(self):
    response = self.client.get(
        '/request/download_template/')
```

Than you have set in your urls:

```
path('request/download_template', ExampleView.as_view()),
```

Notice the slash at the end.

Comment: That slash always gets me. Which is recommended in the urls though? To have slash at the end or not? I see it does not have effect when visiting the endpoints (?).

Comment: I prefer no slashes, but basically it's up to you in most cases.